# How to add contact from telegram group

Tags: python, telegram, contacts, telethon

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions,events
import asyncio

api_id = xxxxxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

async def main():
    client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()
 

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='t.me/PubgMobile2ir_Gruop'))  
    async def handler(event):
      await client(functions.contacts.AddContactRequest(
          id=event.message.sender_id,
          first_name=str(event.message.sender.first_name),
          last_name=str(event.message.sender.last_name),
          phone='',
          add_phone_privacy_exception=True))
  
if True: 
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```

THE ERROR:

ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=6217493693) (PeerUser). Please read https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html to find out more details.

#WHAT I NEED
i need it to get the user from the group when send message and add them to my contact

Comment: Note that Telegram often considers this spam. Your account, and perhaps group, will likely be banned if you abuse the service.